# Spark : Call a custom method before processing rdd on each executor

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a spark Streaming application . I have a requirement where i need to verify certain condition( by reading file present in local FS). 
I tried doing:

```
lines.foreachRDD{rdd =>
verifyCondition
rdd.map() ..

}



def verifyCondition(){
 ...
}
```

But verifyCondition is being executed only by Driver. Is there any way we can execute it by each executors?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to verify that condition once per every element of `lines` RDD? Or you just want to make sure that it's executed on executors?

Comment: I want it to be executed once per every batch of data on all executors and driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move verifyCondition function inside rdd.map() like

```
rdd.map{
  verifyCondition
  ...
}
```

because inside map is a closure(a closure is a record storing a function together with an environment) and spark will distribute it over executors and it will be executed by each executor.

Comment: Will this be executed by both Driver and Executor or only Executor?

Comment: Only on Executor.

Comment: if you want to make it executed on Driver, you can call another verifyCondition before rdd.map() just like what you do.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition => partition
    verifyCondition(...) // This will be executed by executors, once per every partition
    partition.map(...)
  }
}
```